# Issue when trying to install scipy in virtualenv on rpi

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, raspberry-pi3

I'll preface this by saying that I'm quite a newbie at Linux and using my rpi in general.
I'm trying to setup my pi-3b so that it can use opencv in python along with scikit-learn to run a program used in a course I'm attending.
For installing opencv I followed this guide: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/
which seems to have worked fine.
Now I can check numpy version in the virtualenv with python(all good here).
But when I try to install scipy while having the virtualenv active (ie. `(cv) pi@pi`) using the command `pip3 install scipy`, after collecting scipy I get `Building wheels for collected packages: scipy` and`Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ...`
At this point it seems that the process hangs and there is no progress.
I have tried using `pip install scipy` as well, to the same result.
The messages I get when interrupting the process(after 2 hours hang) can be seen here [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqbBk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if pip is not working for you try to use Easy_install

first install it with pip

```
pip install setuptools
```

or if you already have it

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

then try to use easy_install to download it but doing

```
easy_install scipy
```

this should work.
if not let me know and i will try to help you out.

Comment: I cancelled it after running for 3 hours, I got loads of lines from it but it seemed to me that a good part of them were warnings.  
I (think) I ran the easy_install scipy from the virtualenv, not sure whether this might've been to blame